# Can't open the event viewer in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, eventviewer

Yesterday i just finished installing a file server running Windows 2008 to our company.

Now i've noticed that somehow i can't open the event viewer with my standard administrative account.
I've added my standard administrative account as a member to every admin group possible that is:
Administrators, Server Operators, Domain Admins, Enterprise admins, but when i try to open the event viewer on the server it gives me an error msg that says: 
"Windows cannot acces the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item."

The same message goes when i try to access the command prompt and the server manager.

I can still open those consoles if I use the standard Administrator account, but i don't want to use that acc. for everyday work.

I wonder what could be the problem because so far i havent got any problems with privileges on the domain controlers.

Please help, im starting to go nuts!

Comment: Just a shot, but is the server actually properly joined to the domain?

Comment: Yes it is :)
In fact, I'm working on it right now.. it is just that i cant use my standard administrative account to perform administrative tasks on the server. 
I CAN LOG IN on the server but it is like i am loged in with a regular user :S (but it is the same account that i perform the everyday administrative tasks on the domain controlers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something went wrong with the installation or with a program after installation was finished. Reinstall the Operating System.**

I hate to break it to you, but with errors on the operation of basic functions like that, there is no hope but a clean install. I would also be willing to bet that there is some anti-virus program on the server. Make sure that it is *specifically made for Windows Server* and has all of the proper exclusion paths for not only windows Server but for whichever services, roles, features and other applications that you are running on it. I'm suspecting that something has scanned and attempted to fix a few files that it does not have any right tinkering with.

It's also possibly that the server could be infected with a virus. That error message is eerily common with virus infections. Perform an offline scan of the hard drive. Boot up with a Kaspersky / Avira / ClamAV / Whatever boot CD and let it run.

Nothing good can come of that error message, especially when access core tools like the command prompt or server manager. Lock and load, because that crate needs to be blown away.